When one cell equals another, can the font, colour and size also change to equal another cell?
Not sure if this is even possible.
The simple formula of cell A27 '=A2'  so anything I type into A2 will duplicate the text into cell A27, but, A27 only the text copies, is it possible somehow to really duplicate a cell, so that in A27 if I change the font, the font size and font colour for one word, or format something in A2 like wrap text or shrink to fit, the whole thing will exactly duplicate into A27 and all the other cells I have duplicated?
I know copy and paste seems easier, but I have documents that have multiple pages,  orientations and different items, and I use the = in around 10 cells, but if i update something and change the colour of one word and a word to italic, it does't change it in the '=' cells.
Is this something that is possible to do? I don't like the copy and paste into multiple cells as mistakes happen.  Thank you

You can change the colors of a cell using conditional formatting, but it uses predefined colors, not take the colors of an existing cell. But you can format both cells using conditional formatting so they matches.

Thanks,   but I don't want to change the cell colour its the font only, colour and size etc.  but thank you :-)

Conditional formatting includes font, cell color, border and other stuff. So yes, you could use conditional formatting to change the font for that cell.

Not with a formula, because a formula only produces a value. However, there are two possible solutions:

Use the Excel Camera command - this creates an image of a cell or a set of cells which you can position anywhere in your workbook. It shows the cells you've referenced, including their formatting. (Note that to use this command, you may need to add it to the toolbar first)


Write a VBA routine, triggered by a change in your origin columns, that copies the format of those cells into the destination.



You can also create an image using the camera tool and then change the source of that image. For instance, you can change the source to =INDIRECT($D$5) and then put some more complicated formula in D5 that resolves to the address of the cell you want to show up in the image.

Thank you, i've never used camera tool, I will give this a try and see what works best.  Thanks

+1 because I never heard of the camera function. :) You learn something new every day.

That Camera worked absolutely perfect, this is my new favourite tool :-D i'm using it everywhere ha ha,  thank you very much everyone for the help and suggestions :-)

As already mentioned, you can achieve a similar effect with the event macro Worksheet_Change and a properly constructed formula.
The macro will run when you edit any single cell. If you want the cell you are editing to adopt the formatting of the cell it refers to, add a space after the first = sign. This will be a signal for the procedure that it has to work. Without this space, the formatting will not be copied.
Since the cell contains a formula (and I assume it should stay that way), the formatting you copy must apply to the entire cell. If the characters in the source cell are formatted differently, the formatting of the first character is copied.
If the formula in the destination cell references more than 1 cell, the formatting of the first reference in the formula is copied.
The formatting is copied by the cell's Value(11) property, which covers most aspects of the cell's base formatting. A value of 11 corresponds to the constant xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet.
Place the procedure code in the sheet module.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Left(Target.Formula, 2) = "= " Then
        Dim ref As Range, df As String
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ref = Target.DirectPrecedents
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ref Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        df = Target.Formula
        Target.Value(11) = ref(1).Value(11)
        Target.Formula = df
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub

A sample result:


Thank you very much,  i've used the camera tool and its worked perfect, but the macro has come in very useful for something else I was looking at,  thanks again.
